# .Net application windows controls injection

Tags: .net, winforms, legacy

I have a legacy application implemented as windows forms .net application. It allows to script it events (with vbs) but doesn't allow to improve it's UI.

Is it possible to inject some custom user controls into legacy application controls tree in order to communicate with them from script-abilities further?

p.s. legacy application code is missed. It's also impossible to rewrite it from scratch

Answer (score 2):

If you go to great lengths and put in much effort, I'm sure this would be possible using reflection and code re-writing or any such thing. But it would almost certainly be a lot simpler, less time-consuming and less error-prone to simply modify the GUI by changing the source code and then recompiling.

If your GUI isn't meant to be flexible, making it flexible should happen by re-designing or re-factoring the code, not by abusing the existing code into something that it wasn't meant to do.

---

**Update #1:** As said in the comment, since you no longer have the source code, the option of recompiling is gone. Unless you re-wrote the application from scratch or partly retrieved some source code through a reverse engineering tool like .NET Reflector. (Assuming the code hasn't been obfuscated.)

**Update #2:** If you want to go down the route of enumerating `HWND`s (Win32 window handles), you might be interested in a related issue: namely, that of modifying Windows' default file open/save dialogs. If you want to insert or change controls in these dialogs, you basically have to deal with `HWND`s and then manipulate controls through these, using native Win32 API functions.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the code is missed :(  Sorry, I haven't mentioned that from the very beginning

Comment: @Andrew: OK. Depending on how complex your application is, you might want to consider re-writing it, so that it's more flexible to begin with. Or partly retrieve the source code with .NET reflector or any other reverse engineering tool. (That suggestion will work only if the code wasn't obfuscated.)

Comment: Is it possible to use scripting to create my com object from dll (in such case my code will be loaded into executable) and then iterating through handles with win32 native functions find the control i want and convert it back to Windows.Forms.Form instance in order to get access to .Controls property?

Comment: I don't think that's the way to go. But since you asked: I think instead of mixing up Windows API functionality and Winforms, I would forget about Winforms -- I don't think you can easily re-build a `Form` object including all its children `Controls` just from one `HWND` -- and stick with the Win32 API. I believe that it's very well possible to iterate through a process' `HWND`s (to find the form) and to find all child `HWND`s (the controls) of one particular `HWND`.

Comment: Thank you, Stakx. I found Form.FromHandle method though it has limitations to application domain boundaries. It doesn't work for my case